# Contours Export Flat

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, autocad

Im am trying to export my contours from ArcMap to AutoCad from a .tiff. I am able to get the contours extracted and opened in AutoCad but they come out flat. I made sure I was inserting the correct 'contour interval' when extracting contours from the raster but they still come out flat. 
Can any one please help out?

Comment: Are your contours a 3d feature class? I was fairly sure that if environment setting 'output has z values' was set to enabled the outputs would have their heights assigned... not 100% certain though, it could have been another contour utility. If not GDAL_Contour with -3d option will create 3d shape files http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html.

Comment: I have converted it to a tin and still there is no z value attributed when I look in the files properties. I have exported to CAD before but the contours were already formated for me

Comment: When exporting to CAD with ArcMap the *elevation* is an attribute that can be copied: 2d Shape with Elevation to 3d DXF; the 3rd party software endorsed by FelixIP should (could) do the job but I can't say for sure having not used it. I don't work much with CAD (if I can help it). Can you explain more about your CAD conversion and the tool(s) you use? Perhaps there's a switch that needs to be set.

Comment: here are the files Im using https://www.dropbox.com/sh/untszm39yfeqere/AADrQjPLyyRWSD-Vb25VKcjCa?dl=0. As you can see they are flat before evening using the 'export to CAD' tool.

Comment: I can't access Dropbox due to I.T. policy. Have you used Add CAD fields http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_CAD_Fields/001200000019000000/ on the shape? This tool gives you all the fields that Export to CAD http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Export_To_CAD/00120000001n000000/ is looking for, this gives you an opportunity to copy the height of the contours into the elevation field, then use a 3d CAD seed file to ensure the output is 3d.

Comment: Ive refined the problem to being the conversion from the raster to contours in ARCMAP (Ive tried converting using a .tiff and a TIN). The raster is definitely 3d as I have checked in ARC Scence but the contours still have no vertical valves. I suspect I am missing an important step when converting....Im use both 'Contour (tool)' and 'Surface contour(tool)' repectively

Answer (score 2):

To convert 2d contours into 3d use [OGR2OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) with a few switches:

```
-dim 3 -zfield Z_Field_Name
```

Example: In this case the field with the elevations is called 'Altitude'

```
ogr2ogr D:\SomePath\Output3d_ogr.shp D:\SomePath\Input2d.shp -dim 3 -zfield Altitude
```

Or even better still, directly to DXF with OGR2OGR:

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF D:\SomePath\Output3d.DXF D:\SomePath\Input2d.shp -dim 3 -zfield Altitude
```

Input (Esri) contours, clearly 2d data:

[image: 2d contour description in ArcCatalog]

Output (OGR) contours, have been converted to 3d shape:

[image: 3d contour description in ArcCatalog]

And in ArcScene:
[image: Both contours in ArcScene]

The 2d contours (black) are flat and the 3d contours from OGR are neatly above them. I only hope your export tool uses the 3d geometry to create a 3d CAD file, if you have troubles I know `OGR2OGR -f DXF` will convert to a 3d DXF.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS does not transfer Z attribute when exporting to CAD. Seek 3rd party software, something like arc2cad.